# Is it possible to programmatically add built-in command to Add-in ribbon tab?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins, ribbonx, word-web-addins

We have built a Word Add-In using the Office Add-in platform SDKs (JavaScript).

The Add-In includes a custom ribbon tab (defined in the Manifest.xml). We've been asked to add the "Text Styles" built-in command button to the custom ribbon. It's possible to add this manually by right-clicking and customising the toolbar.

[[image]]

We'd like to roll this out to all users on a larger scale – is it possible to add this customisation programmatically through our Add-In (manifest.xml)?

I've tried to change the manifest.xml file to reference the StylesPane command but this wasn't successful. I've also researched other ways to customise the "Office Fluent Ribbon" by following the links in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers), specifically [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3) | Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.14).aspx) however these instructions seem to be targeted to the older COM add-in model for Office and not the newer JavaScript-based Office Add-in platform.

Is it even possible to add or reference built-in commands in a custom ribbon?

Answer (score 2):

You can insert built-in Office buttons into your custom control groups on the Office ribbon by using markup in the add-in's manifest. You can also insert entire built-in Office control groups into your custom ribbon tabs.

To insert a built-in Office control into a custom group, add an OfficeControl element as a child element in the parent  element. The id attribute of the  element is set to the ID of the built-in control. See [Find the IDs of controls and control groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/built-in-button-integration#find-the-ids-of-controls-and-control-groups).

The following markup example adds the Office `Superscript` control to a custom group and positions it to appear just after a custom button:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContosoRibbonTab">
  <CustomTab id="Contoso.TabCustom2">
    <Group id="Contoso.TabCustom2.group1">
        <Label resid="residCustomTabGroupLabel"/>
        <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="blue-icon-16" />
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="blue-icon-32" />
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="blue-icon-80" />
        </Icon>
        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.Button1">
            <!-- information on the control omitted -->
        </Control>
        <OfficeControl id="Superscript" />
        <!-- other controls, as needed -->
    </Group>
    <Label resid="customTabLabel1" />
  </CustomTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Read more about that in the [Integrate built-in Office buttons into custom control groups and tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/built-in-button-integration) article.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. This looked really promising until I read "In particular, only PowerPoint add-ins are supported at this time" from: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-control-ids ☹️

Comment: It seems need to wait until the requirement set will be supported by your host application. Design your add-in to have an experience when the `AddinCommands 1.3` requirement set isn't supported, as described in [Design for alternate experiences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#design-for-alternate-experiences). For example, if your add-in contains instructions that assume the built-in buttons are in your custom groups, you could design a version that assumes that the built-in buttons are only in their usual places.